# StreamSets get MongoDB fields

Tags: mongodb, streamsets

I would like to ask if anyone knows if StreamSets can also get a field which does not exist in every MongoDB records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Also specify what problems you are facing and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

StreamSets Data Collector follows a 'schema on read' model - it will read records from a MongoDB collection whether they have the same fields or different.

Answer (score 0):

If you read some document from mongodb which doesn't contain some field you want it to contain then you can add some SDC component like **expression evaluator** or **groovy script** to add this field programmaticaly after reading from mongodb.